# Closing websocket connection on disconnect or refreshing

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am using a SockJS client side library to connect to a server which is using SockJS node js library.

When the web page refreshes everytime it makes a new web socket connection with the server. And the previous connection does not get disconnected. So if there is 5 refreshes there would be 5 different web socket connections.

How can I check if a web socket connection is active and prevent new connections from creating or disconnect existing connection on page reload or in a network disconnection?

Answer (score 3):

Each new page is its own new context, and everything from the old context gets discarded browser-side. So there is no way to preserve a WebSocket connection across page loads.

In your situation, on the browser side you actually only have a single WebSocket connection at any time: That established by the newly reloaded page.

The problem on the server side is that there is no way to differentiate a disconnect from an inactive/very slow connection if there is no traffic.

One way around this is to use heartbeats, i.e. a regular ping/pong of messages between the server and the browser. WebSocket supports this at the protocol level, and server-side WebSocket libraries should expose this mechanism. This is useful in any case since it works irrespective of how the disconnect happens (e.g. for network failures).

For a reload you should attach a handler to the relevant event (`beforeunload`) and then do a clean disconnect. You'd catch this with the heartbeat as well, but this way you can react before the next heartbeat fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent this situation, but you can do *heartbeats* from the *Web Socket server* to detect stale clients and drop the connection from the server-side.

Perhaps you can take a look at [this MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Pings_and_Pongs_The_Heartbeat_of_WebSockets):

> At any point after the handshake, either the client or the server can
>   choose to send a ping to the other party. When the ping is received,
>   the recipient must send back a pong as soon as possible. You can use
>   this to make sure that the client is still connected, for example.